# Android Material CardView with ConstraintLayout clip child not working

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview, materialcardview

I want to overlap (take half the image outside) of the card view. The `ShapeableImageView` is a child of the card view.

I have tried adding `clipChilder="false"` on card view as well as on the child constraint layout but no luck. I also tried the same in runtime again no luck.

## Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.ProfileFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.codepaints.velvet.views.HeaderView
            android:id="@+id/v_profile_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="235dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_profile_bg"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:overlay_color="@color/colorNavHeaderOverlay" />

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/v_profile_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/app_space"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/app_space"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:translationY="-24dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/app_space_h"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/app_shadow_two"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/v_profile_header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/v_profile_header"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/v_profile_header"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_profile_header"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/v_profile_card_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipChildren="false">

                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/v_profile_avatar"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_avatar_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_avatar_size"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_border"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_profile_avatar"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"/>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/v_profile_online_status_holder"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/app_space"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_space"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_profile_avatar"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_profile_avatar"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/v_profile_avatar" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/v_profile_online_status"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/app_space"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_space"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_space_h"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_circle"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorOnline"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/v_profile_online_status_holder"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_profile_avatar"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_profile_avatar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/v_profile_username"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/profile_username"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_profile_avatar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/v_profile_qualification"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_university"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/app_space_q"
                    android:text="@string/profile_qualification"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_profile_username" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

## Screenshot

[image]

## Another Test

> I have tried out without MaterialCardView but the result is the same.
>   I have no idea why it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.ProfileFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/v_profile_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        app:elevation="1dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <ImageView
            app:elevation="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/v_image"
            android:layout_width="128dp"
            android:layout_height="128dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_profile_avatar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/v_user"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/profile_username"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/v_image"
            android:background="@color/colorNutritionKcal"
            android:translationY="60dp"
            android:elevation="100dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

## Screenshot

[image]

## Test 3

> It won't work with LinearLayout too :(

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/v_profile_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <ImageView
        android:elevation="@dimen/app_space"
        android:id="@+id/v_image"
        android:layout_width="128dp"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:translationY="-60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_profile_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/v_user"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/profile_username"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/v_image"
        android:background="@color/colorNutritionKcal"
        android:translationY="60dp"
        android:elevation="100dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Add `android:clipChildren="false"` to your top-level _ConstraintLayout_ and remove it elsewhere. The inner layout is only too happy to draw outside the box. It is the top-level group that is clipping its children.

Comment: That option is not working too. I wonder it a bug, or is this the way it is?

Comment: I have tried using `constraintlayout` as a root layout instead of `ScrollView` and that seems working if I have something like `ConstraintLayout > ConstraintLayout > ImageView` but in the first structure I shared in question, that didn't make any difference if I add `clipChildren` to the parent constraint layout or even scrollview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after trying so many different ways, finally found the solution.

In my case, I have an image wrapped by a card view, and the card view is inside a constraint layout. So here I have to set `android:clipChildren="false"` for both views, `ConstraintLayout` the parent and the `CardView` a child. See the final code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.ProfileFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <com.codepaints.velvet.views.HeaderView
            android:id="@+id/v_profile_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="235dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img_profile_bg"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:overlay_color="@color/colorNavHeaderOverlay" />

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/v_profile_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/app_space"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/app_space"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:translationY="-24dp"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/app_space_h"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/app_shadow_two"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/v_profile_header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/v_profile_header"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/v_profile_header"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_profile_header"
            app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/v_profile_card_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
                    android:id="@+id/v_profile_avatar"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_avatar_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_avatar_size"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_circle_border"
                    android:src="@drawable/img_profile_avatar"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"/>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/v_profile_online_status_holder"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/app_space"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_space"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_profile_avatar"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_profile_avatar"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/v_profile_avatar" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/v_profile_online_status"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/app_space"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_space"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_space_h"
                    android:background="@drawable/shape_circle"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorOnline"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/v_profile_online_status_holder"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/v_profile_avatar"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/v_profile_avatar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/v_profile_username"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/profile_username"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_profile_avatar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/v_profile_qualification"
                    style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_university"
                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/app_space_q"
                    android:text="@string/profile_qualification"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/v_profile_username" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case you can add this to MaterialCardView xml file

```
android:outlineProvider="none"
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the issue for me!